# Any consideration for image classification when one class has generally one particular color

Tags: keras, image-classification

I am trying to predict rooftop orientations among: horizontal, vertical, flat, unknown.

The particularity of horizontal and vertical rooftops, is that it's color generally is reddish, the reason of tiles. The flat ones, I would say, most are blue to grey. This is just an eye perception.

Is there a intelligent consideration to put the third dimension which is color on focus ?

The third dimension goes for the RGB channel.

My model is like

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(96, 96, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# the model so far outputs 3D feature maps (height, width, features)

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4))

model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```